# How to convert one dimensional array into two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my code

```js
const arrayColumn = (arr, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]);
const pcorr = (x, y) => {
  let sumX = 0,
    sumY = 0,
    sumXY = 0,
    sumX2 = 0,
    sumY2 = 0;
  const minLength = x.length = y.length = Math.min(x.length, y.length),
    reduce = (xi, idx) => {
      const yi = y[idx];
      sumX += xi;
      sumY += yi;
      sumXY += xi * yi;
      sumX2 += xi * xi;
      sumY2 += yi * yi;
    }
  x.forEach(reduce);
  return (minLength * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / Math.sqrt((minLength * sumX2 - sumX * sumX) * (minLength * sumY2 - sumY * sumY));
};

//create pearson correlation matrix
        var r = [[]];
        var r_temp = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= _arrData[0].length; j++) {
            r_temp.push(pcorr(arrayColumn(_arrData,i-1),arrayColumn(_arrData,j-1)));
          }
        }
        
        var r_temp_length = r_temp.length;
        for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= _arrData[0].length; j++) {
            r[i - 1][j - 1] = r_temp[_arrData[0].length^2 - r_temp_length];
            r_temp_length = r_temp_length - 1;
          }
        }
```

_arrData is the data from .csv file that already read as matrix 43X4
r_temp result is

```
[1, 0.1001546791334383, -0.09722360940329312, -0.1119017933192886, 0.1001546791334383, 1, 0.19766088533723247, -0.03844791092325515, -0.09722360940329312, 0.19766088533723247, 1, -0.06161560854254137, -0.1119017933192886, -0.03844791092325515, -0.06161560854254137, 1]
```

r_temp length is 16

I want to input the r_temp value into r which is gonna be 4x4 Matrix

When I run this code, there's error from this part

```
r[i - 1][j - 1] = r_temp[_arrData[0].length^2 - r_temp_length];
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: *there's error from this part* What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined @gurvinder372

Comment: what is `^` doing? usually it is a [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) operator.

Comment: I code in R before implement in javascript,
I guess ^ is for exponent??

Comment: thank you @NinaScholz, exponent in javascript is Math.pow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var r = [];
```

...

```
for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
    r[i - 1] = [];
```

....

It should be var r = []; instead of [[]].

In your code the line r[i - 1] = []; is missing.

It creates the second array for r[i - 1].

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, it works!

```js
//create pearson correlation matrix
        var r = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
          r[i - 1] = [];
        }
        var r_temp = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= _arrData[0].length; j++) {
            r_temp.push(pcorr(arrayColumn(_arrData,i-1),arrayColumn(_arrData,j-1)));
          }
        }
        var r_temp_length = r_temp.length;
        for (var i = 1; i <= _arrData[0].length; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= _arrData[0].length; j++) {
            r[i - 1][j - 1] = r_temp[Math.pow(_arrData[0].length,2) - r_temp_length];
            r_temp_length = r_temp_length - 1;
          }
        }
```